# How to output False in a list if all numbers are less than 100 in SWI-Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

So this is what I have in SWI-Prolog

```
:- style_check(-singleton).

first_big([NumList], First).
first_big([X|Xs], R):- first_big(Xs, T), (X > 100 -> R = X ; R = T).
```

And I want to output false if any number in the list is less than 100 using this

first_big([1,20,3,1,50,10,6],First).
should be false

first_big([1,200,3,1,50,10,6],First).
should be true

I have also tried these but no luck

```
%first_big([X|Xs], R):- first_big(Xs, T), X < 100, R is False.

%first_big([], _):- 0.
%first_big([NumList < 100], false).
```

Comment: `maplist(>(100),[1,20,3,1,50,10,6]).`

Comment: And: do **not** turn off singleton checking

Comment: "And I want to output false" Better: "I want the predicate to fail". Some [examples for maplist/2](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/blob/master/maplist/maplist_2_examples.md). Tell me if it's readable.

Comment: Perhaps a hint to reformulate your problem: your predicate should fail if (and only if) there exists an element of the list that is < 100. Try to formulate it as "the predicate should succeed if for all elements [...]" holds. The [...] part can be written without negation.